# JavaFx Dialog remove bottom space

Tags: javafx, dialog, padding, space

Consider following code:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch( args );
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final BorderPane p = new BorderPane();

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog() { {
            getDialogPane().setContent( new Button( "TEXT" ) );
        } };

        final Button bt = new Button( "LAUNCH" );
        bt.setOnAction( e -> dialog.show() );

        p.setCenter( bt );

        stage.setScene( new Scene( p ));

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Result is:

[image]

Code is simplified example.

Trouble is with the extra space at the bottom. Is there any way to remove it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage)
{
    final BorderPane p = new BorderPane();

    Stage dialog = new Stage();
    dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    dialog.setScene(new Scene(new Button("TEXT")));               

    final Button bt = new Button( "LAUNCH" );
    bt.setOnAction( e -> dialog.show() );

    p.setCenter( bt );

    stage.setScene( new Scene( p ));

    stage.show();
}
```

[image]

Comment: This will show another icon in the task bar. Stage != Dialog

Comment: Yes, that working! Thank you!
I've tried to find reason of such behaviour before answering, but didn't succeed. Bottom space disappears if we use initStyle( StageStyle.UNDECORATED ), but also we loose frame!

Answer (score 1):

Define a style file "style.css" in the same package as your class with this selector:

```css
.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

In the Java code set the style sheet:

```java
dialog.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it:

```java
dialog.getDialogPane().setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
```